# Appending files that end with .log to a txt file without the .log

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

Say I have a bunch of files:

```
blar23123.log
blar23131.log
blar11111.txt
blar55532.log
```

I want to output all the ones that end in the .log into a text file without the .log.

**Expected output (text file):**

```
 blar23123
 blar23131
 blar55532
```

I have a pretty botch way of doing this, I create the files a new seperate files without the .log. But As I'm working on data sets of 100000 files it can be an exhaustive job and take a while.

**What I have been doing:**

```
for file in *.log; do cp -- "$file" "${file%%.log}"; done
```

And then I have been been listing them and then appending them to a txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want:

```
for file in *.log ; do
    echo "${file%.*}"
done > output.txt
```

`${file%.*}` is a so called [parameter expansion](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html). In this case it removes the shortest match of a dot followed by arbitrary characters from the end for `$file`. This will effectively remove the file extension.

Comment: Only outputs one to the txt file

Comment: You redirected the output of every `echo`. I suggested to redirect the output of the `for` loop which is more efficient. (Check the code carefully)